# Unwanted Default Button Animation

Tags: swift, xcode

I created a button which title shows a timer. Now my problem is that it has an unwanted whatever animation, see below.

Link to see Animation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2z2kzcoGO6s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your button of type system? If it is, try to set it to custom in the attributes inspector. It works for me.

Comment: Do you know how can I change it to custom programmatically?

Comment: If you need to change it with code, I think you have to create it programmatically.